# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'

Tags: reactjs, file, frontend

I have tried going through various ways to resolve this but none worked. Then I thought maybe this issue was related to some files.
I went and checked all my files when I got the following pop-up:
[image]
This pop-up comes up in VSCode, while in PyCharm it simply gives a blank file.
What might be the solution here?

The files which are not opening are giving this symbol when viewing there properties (if this helps):
[image]

This is all the information I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to open a file stored in OneDrive.

In this case, it could be that the file isn't actually downloaded and/or accessible.

You should try to move the file to a local directory outside of your OneDrive directory.

Comment: The problem got solved! Actually the apps in OneDrive were let on sync that caused the problem.